# What are all the ways to get Speech Bonuses in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

What are all the ways to get Speech bonuses in Skyrim?  I want to maximize the amount of gold I get when selling to a vendor.

Comment: Do you want to know which actions (i.e. selling items, bribing guards...) increase the Speech, or rather the temporary bonuses, such as buffs?

Comment: Selling items and persuading people does (I've leveled up Speech on doing those).  Not sure about others.  It seems like a reasonable question to ask if you want answers from the wider community.  I did a search and didn't see it so you wouldn't be duplicating an existing question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know of the following ways to get bonuses:

1. Blessing of Zenithar (Pray at one of his shrines 10%)
2. Charity (Give a gold to a begger for an 8 hour buff)
3. A potion of speech called elixir of glibness (Gives +40 speech for 60 seconds)
4. Items with Fortify Speech enchantment (marked "of Haggling" or similar, Max modifier is 40 and can only be enchanted on necklaces)
5. Haggling (5-30% price improvement) and Allure (10% better prices with opposite sex) perks under speech skill.
6. The thieves guild hoods (regular, improved, and grandmaster) all come with enchantments that improve prices.  This is the only way to get this enchantment on headgear.
7. Potions of fortify barter can be made via alchemy.

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer, but an edit in your question.

Comment: @Magicmaster No it shouldn't: it's an actual answer to the question, and self-answering [is encouraged here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: @MarkTrapp I supposed he wants to know other possible bonuses. But you are right, pardon me.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for other bonuses I don't know about.  It feels weird answering your own question, but I read somewhere it's actually encouraged on the site.  Plus I thought what I already know would help get a relevant answer and maybe help others.

Comment: @Cloudancer — There is a Potion of Haggling as well.

Answer (score 0):

on the main quest you need to enter the Thalmor embassy as a guest and someone there asks you to bring him some wine.
the wine can be taken from the bar-man there just take many for yourself and they give you boost of better prices.